# VBA Change Sourcedata Line Color

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to change the line of my fullseries sourcedata rangey3.

I tried using:

```
.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(56, 182, 75)
.MarkerBackgroundColor = RGB(56, 182, 75)
```

to no avail but it does work for the forecasted values.

My code is:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(332, xlLineMarkers).Select
With ActiveChart
.SetSourceData Source:=rangey3
' Must have this as we will be using different series inside of this chart from here on out
.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "Demand"
' This is the first series of the full series collection
.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = rangex
.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
' Creates legend at the bottom of the chart
.SetElement (msoElementLegendBottom)
' Deletes the chart title as per the illustration in Assignment 2's illustration screenshot
.ChartTitle.Delete

' Creates the line Demand (Forecast)
With .SeriesCollection(2)
    .Name = "Demand (Forecast)"
    .Values = rangey2
    .Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue
    ' Makes the forecast line distinguishable by dotting it
    .Format.Line.DashStyle = msoLineSysDot
    .Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(56, 182, 75)
    .MarkerBackgroundColor = RGB(56, 182, 75)
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use for each statement.

```
Dim Srs As Series

ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(332, xlLineMarkers).Select
With ActiveChart
    .SetSourceData Source:=rangey3
    ' Must have this as we will be using different series inside of this chart from here on out
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "Demand"
    ' This is the first series of the full series collection
    .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = rangex
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ' Creates legend at the bottom of the chart
    .SetElement (msoElementLegendBottom)
    ' Deletes the chart title as per the illustration in Assignment 2's illustration screenshot
    .ChartTitle.Delete

    ' Creates the line Demand (Forecast)
    With .SeriesCollection(2)
        .Name = "Demand (Forecast)"
        .Values = rangey2
        .Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue
    End With
    ' Makes the forecast line distinguishable by dotting it
    For Each Srs In .SeriesCollection
        With Srs
            .Format.Line.DashStyle = msoLineSysDot
            .Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(56, 182, 75)
            .MarkerBackgroundColor = RGB(56, 182, 75)
        End With
    Next Srs
End With
```

Comment: How would this look if I want rangey3 to be solid and randey2 to be dashed?

Comment: @PaperCupStraw, set each collection format dashstryle. collection(1), collection(2).